# macOS Sierra 10.12.6: Quicktime Edit options unavailable

Tags: macos, quicktime

I am unable to do anything meaningful in Quicktime, as the Edit options (as well as those from other tabs) are inaccessible. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a document open? That's exactly how the Edit menu should look if you don't have any media open currently.

Comment: @grg, I am trying to layer an audio clip onto a screen capture. This is the output I get when I have the audio file open. I get the output you mentioned when I have the video file open, however.